# Update cells formatting with the Google Sheets API (Wrapping and Alignment)

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I need to wrap and align all the cells in the spreadsheet.

So far, I came up with this request that I send to a spreadsheet with spreadsheet.batch_update

```
        requests =[{
                    "updateCells": {
                        "range": {
                            "sheetId": self.sheet.id,
                        },
                        "rows": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                            {
                                "userEnteredFormat": {
                                    "wrapStrategy": "WRAP",
                                    "verticalAlignment": "TOP"
                                }
                            }]
                        }],
                        "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
                    }
                }]
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reflect `"wrapStrategy": "WRAP"` and `"verticalAlignment": "TOP"` in all cells in a sheet of Google Spreadsheet using the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.

In your request body, only cell "A1" is used. In order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification using RepeatCellRequest?

#### Modified script:

```
requests = [
    {
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": {"sheetId": self.sheet.id},
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "wrapStrategy": "WRAP",
                    "verticalAlignment": "TOP",
                }
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat.wrapStrategy,userEnteredFormat.verticalAlignment",
        }
    }
]
```

#### Reference:

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)